# Crystal Report graph not showing properly

Tags: crystal-reports, vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-viewer

I have 2 graphs in one report:

[image]

The top graph has 2 similar points, which each points showing itself as is, I have encircled the points in brown just to be clear.

The graph below the first one has a similar point also, which I encircled in blue, but the problem is it does not reflect the same as the top graph, Is there a fix for this problem?

Here are the things which I have tried.

1) I Deleted the graph below, copied the graph above and pasted it on the location of the below graph, then put put the necessary data to be populated, the graph produces the error.

2) I created another line graph, with the necessary data to be populated, the graph produces the error

I am using the default graph of crystal reports viewer

This is the Raw Data of the graphs, I encircled the data of the first graph in red. The data of the second graph is encircled in blue.

[image: Raw data of graph]

This is the data without the circles.

[image]

I used the Chart wizard to create these charts, the 1st screenshot is for the 1st graph.

[image]

This is for the 2nd graph

[image]

Comment: hi, what's wrong with #2?

Comment: ...and what's wrong with the first graph? The line between the two points is blue. I don't see what's wrong with either graph.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Sorry for the late reply, I had surgery and could not use the PC for 1 week. The 1st graph shows a correct graph, where if the graph encounters 2 similar points, It would produce 2 similar points as well, but the second graph produces 1 point only, where it should produce 2 similar points also.

Comment: @dd4711 The problem lies in the second graph, which I have encircled in blue. The graph should show 2 similar points, but it just produced 1 point.

Comment: can you please post your raw data

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I have posted the raw data as screenshots, thank you!

Comment: Please do ignore if you found out that the graph and the data are not equal, specifically the last part, in my graph, the first graph still produces my desired result, and the second graph, it still merges same data.

Comment: can you please post the graph x and y definition for both

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Noted ! I have updated my post as per your request.

Comment: definitely not the same.. so basically this is a formula issue or the behaviour issue. what you can do to validate is if you setup the 2nd graph to act as the 1st graph - this should give you the same result meaning your 2nd config has the issue

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I tried your suggestion, I put the data of the second graph to the first, and I have reproduced the error. as per the formula, I just rounded the data into 2 decimal places, If it is behavioral, how could I resolve it?

Comment: If you really want me to solve this attach the table and crystal report. It is really hard just to see a screenshot.

Comment: May I ask you to put a answer here, so I may award you, I think It would be hard and time consuming if you will answer it, the data is composed of formulas from a stored procedure, and I thank you for the time you have given me, atleast, the insight on putting the data of the second table is enough for me to reproduce the error. I would use this to resolve the problem.

Comment: @Mr.J What value of your table is used for the x-axis?

Comment: @dd4711 as my graph is created via Graph wizard of crystal reports, the X axis is automatically created by crystal report.

Comment: @Mr.J But the x-axis has to have a dimension/scale. Your 2nd screenshot shows "On change of R -O". What are the values of R-O? It may be possible that the values that go into R and O produce the same result for your two values, so they are printed together. is "R-O" rounded? You may try to scale that up, use a factor for testing purposes.

Comment: @dd4711 Yes, the Values of R is the same, And the average is a bit different, without rounding up, it produces different values, while R is constant, is that the reason why the merge occurs? can't I separate two similar points?

Comment: @Mr.J You have to find a way to make similar/same values distinct. If the values are really the same you have two measures for the same point on X. If the measures have the same value I would say it's ok to print only one dot on your chart. If they are the same but should be different: change your rounding (add a digit), detect same values and add manually something to make them distinct (ouch!). If the values are very similar change the scale of X, e.g. plot fewer measurements. But I think you  now have found the cause - same X values for two points. Hope this helps.

Comment: @dd4711 Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two points in the second chart are printed on each other because they have (nearly) the same value for X. Additionally Y is the same for both points - it looks like one point is missing.